# What is the better thank you message, after user submits contact request?

Tags: web-app, copywriting, contact-us

After user submits some question or suggestion on the contact page he is redirected to the "Thank you page".

Which is the better way to say thanks and tell how soon will they get their reply?
(we, unfortunately, can't say the exact time, because for working days it's up to an hour, but on weekdays and bank holidays it might take up to several days to get a response.)

**Thank you for contacting us, we will get back to you as soon as possible.**

**Thank you for contacting us, we will reach back to you in a short time.**

**Thank you for getting in touch, we will get back to you as soon as possible.**

**Thank you for getting in touch, we will reach back to you in a short time.**

Comment: Just a grammatical note:  all of those sentences are [comma splices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_splice).

Comment: The simple fix for the comma splice is to replace with a semicolon.

Comment: SE usually gets back to us in 6-8 weeks. ;)

Comment: From the link, comma splices do not seem to be incorrect grammar. Why is it mentioned? Jane Austen has occasionalyl used them in her publishing.

Comment: @NVZ Sony Ericsson? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. If you are not willing to commit publicly to a specific time frame for the response, it is better to say ***as soon as possible*** than the nebulous ***short time***. If you *are* willing to publicly commit to a response time frame, use it: ***Thank you for contacting us; we will respond within three business days.*** (Note: ***Business days*** generally excludes weekends and [bank] holidays; if the customer submits the request late Friday, and you've given yourself three business days, Saturday and Sunday don't count against you; they should accept a response as being within your limit up to close-of-business on the following Wednesday.)
2. I've never seen/heard the usage ***reach back*** for this; the normal usage that I see is ***get back*** for 'casual' responses, or ***respond*** for more formal/businesslike responses: ***Thank you for contacting us; we will respond as soon as possible.***

Comment: Reach back is usually used to express physically moving (like reaching back to grab a book off a shelf). It is indeed a weird way to phrase getting back to someone. I like your suggestion, it's very clear on how long it takes (3 days is defined, 'short time' is not).

Comment: Saturday is a normal work day in most of the western world, although most people don't actually work on Saturdays. Sundays and holidays are not work days, not more, not less.

Comment: @Polygnome Wikipedia Business day: "A business day is considered every official work day of the week. Another common term is work day. Typically, these are the days between and including Monday to Friday and do not include public holidays and weekends."

Comment: @Polygnome I would hazard a guess that english is your second language and that your primary language is German (especially considering you studied in Germany), which would explain your confusion between Werktage and Business days. Please refer to the 'German speaking countries' section of the Wikipedia Business day article.

Answer (score 4):

**Thank you for contacting us, we will reach back to you in a short time.**

"Short" is to vague. For some people "Short" might be one hour, for some it will be 1 day, for some it will be 30 minutes. Your setting the bar pretty high here since most users don't expect to wait longer then 1 hour. If you might need 1 day most people will get frustrated.

**Thank you for contacting us, we will get back to you as soon as possible.**

This is the better option but is also lacking since the user might feel forgotten when he waits 2 days for a reply.

A better option would be:
**Thank you for getting in touch, we always try our best to respond as soon as possible, you can expect a reply in at most 48 hours**.

48 hours in this case is the longest time it usually takes, this timeframe might vary in your case.

**The good:**

you have a pretty big timeframe to work with and the customer expects a reply in 48 hours, if you reply sooner he will probably be really satisfied.

If you track how long your team needs on average for responding you can use these timeframes to provide even better info for the user.

Answer (score 2):

I have a different perspective:

- **The message is a thank you *from the system,*** not actually from a real person (yet).  It's okay to be open about this and not try to phrase the response as though it really came from the customer support team.

  It didn't.  They haven't yet looked at the message.

  (I have a friend I'll call John who once had a voicemail message which began, "Hello, this is John's voicemail.  You haven't yet reached *me,* but you HAVE reached my voicemail!")
- Saying anything about "business days" sounds stuffy and formal.  If you *must* put it in, put it in small print.  At the bottom.
- What I usually want to know from such a system is *what has happened* to my message.  The system should say this.  Have I "gotten in touch" with a machine, or a person?
- There's nothing wrong with "shortly" in my opinion, but "get back to you shortly" makes it sound like it will be more prompt (like they know you are actively waiting for a phone call).  I would avoid saying "get back to you" or anything with "back" because *a human has not yet looked at the message.*

With all that in mind, I would suggest a wording more like:

**Your message has been forwarded to the customer support team, who will contact you shortly.  Thank you!**

<sub>I don't think "shortly" is misleading in this case, as it's not falsely implied that a *person* has already looked at the message (think: grandmothers using computers), and "up to *one business hour*" is actually better than a typical expectancy for what "shortly" means in the *non*-computerized business world.</sub>